# Fast way to check if a string is in a huge text file

Tags: python, file, text

I'm looking for an easy way to check if all the strings that are in a list are in a huge text file (>35.000 words).

```
self.vierkant = ['BIT', 'ICE', 'TEN']


def geldig(self, file):
    self.file = file
    file = open(self.file, 'r')
    line = file.readline()
    self.file = ''

    while line:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        self.file += line
        line = file.readline()

    return len([woord for woord in self.vierkant if woord.lower() not in self.file]) == 0
```

I just copy the text file into self.file, then check if all words from self.vierkant are in self.file.

The main problem is that it takes a very long time to read in the text file.
Is there an easier/faster way to do this?

Comment: You can read the entire text into memory at once, which is slow, but then you can test the strings entirely in memory, which is fast, rather than reading one line at a time. Test if it's a gain.

Comment: How? I usually only read txt files line by line.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but [flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) library looks promising. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/regex-was-taking-5-days-flashtext-does-it-in-15-minutes-55f04411025f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the entire contents of a file with `file.read()` instead of calling `readline()` repeatedly and concatenating the result:

```
with open(self.file) as f:
    self.file = f.read()
```

If you need to check a lot of words, you could also build a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) from the file's contents for O(1) containment checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
    s = set(f.read().splitlines())  # splitlines will remove the '\n' in the end and return a list of line.
for line in test_lines:
    line in s  # O(1) check if the the line in the line-set
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]

Comment: @Blag I added some comments.